# How to mark a field as not to be expanded by JAXB in JAXRS

Tags: java, json, web-services, jaxb, jax-rs

I have 2 classes as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class User {

    @Persistent(primaryKey="true", valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private UserDetails userDetails;
...
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class UserDetails {
    private String streetaddress;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private int pincode;
    private Date dateofbirth;
...
}
```

I need to retrieve the user objects only, without having the userdetails in one JAXRS function, and both the user object and its attached userdetails object in another as shown.

```
//UserManager.java
public List<User> getUsers() {
    javax.jdo.Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM "+ User.class.getName());
    List<User> users = (List<User>) q.execute();
    return users;
}
```

and the JAXRS service:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})  
public List<User> getUsers() {        //Retrieves all users and user details
    UserManager um=new UserManager(); //working perfectly
    return um.getUsers();
}

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})  
public List<User> getUsers() {        //should retrieve user only, but how?
    UserManager um=new UserManager();
    return ?????
}
```

How can I prevent the UserDetails object from being expanded by JAXRS and JAXB for the second function???

Answer (score 0):

if you are returning same type from both functions then jaxb can't help you in hiding information from one method and showing in second.

there are two ways to achieve this:

1) either return different user object fron second function which does not aggregate userdetails.
2) in second function write a query that does not populate user details data.

Comment: How can i do it? can you please give an example.

Comment: Sorry, i am unable to type complete example due to sort of time. i will recommend to populate only basic user data and leave out userdetails using some jpa functionality. if it urgent then assign null to userdeatils reference after populated data, till you fing correct code.

Comment: yup, @lokesh, that was what I was thinking of, but here, User is a datanuclueus JDO entity. The problem is, I don't know how to leave out the userdetails when querying the database.

Comment: update: i think jdo inheritance may work here, although I am not sure how it is done.

Comment: update: I managed to make it work by splitting the User class by using @Inheritance(customStrategy = "complete-table"). However, right now, i can't get the details to be displayed together.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the use of JDO fetch plans and lifecycle policies.

Create a named fetch group for your userDetails e.g.

```
@FetchGroup(name="details", members={@Persistent(name="userDetails")})
```

When you want everything, you don't have to do anything technically because JAXB is navigating the graph, but to be complete you'd  specify this fetch plan and make your returned object transient following the fetch plan, e.g.:

```
pm.getFetchPlan().addGroup("details");
[...]
return (List<User>)pm.makeTransientAll(um.getUsers(), true); // use fetch plan
```

When you want the shallow fetch, use the default fetch plan and make your returned object transient, e.g.:

```
return (List<User>)pm.makeTransientAll(um.getUsers(), true); // use fetch plan
```

Hope it helps.